# Set currency for dynamic gridview cells in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview, aspxgridview

I have a dynamic gridview and formatting needs to be applied for certain columns.

**Code:**

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                string strHeader = GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text;
                List<string> lstCurrency = new List<string>() { "Price", "Amount" };
                bool checkAmount = lstCurrency.Exists(o => strHeader.Equals(o));
                if (checkAmount)
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[i].Text = String.Format("{0:C2}", e.Row.Cells[i].Text);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If gridview column header text contains `Price` or `Amount` then currency formatting needs to be applied and the above code doesn't work.

Please correct me if I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert string `e.Row.Cells[i].Text` into `decimal`:

```
e.Row.Cells[i].Text = String.Format("{0:C2}", Convert.ToDecimal(e.Row.Cells[i].Text));
```

Comment: But it doesn't change formatting for all rows. For ex: If I have 200 rows the formatting applies only for few rows.

Comment: @vicky: Well, there could be many reasons that cause that. You'd better set breakpoint inside `for` loop to check. For example, `strHeader` could be lower-cased 'price', etc.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried parsing the value? Use Int or Decimal as per your requirement.

```
e.Row.Cells[i].Text = String.Format("{0:C2}", Int32.Parse(e.Row.Cells[i].Text));
```